# Null pointer exception on creating Spring bean with JPA configration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have Spring based application and I need to get Hibernate working. So I got inspired by this tutorial: [A Guide to Hibernate with Spring 4](http://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa) and I created java class(I want to configure Hibernate xml-less):

```
    package com.mycompany.cmms.web.config;



import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistanceJPAConfig {


    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
       LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
       em.setDataSource(dataSource());
       em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.vsb.cmms.domain" });

       JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
       em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
       em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

       return em.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
       DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
       dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
       dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/cmms");
       dataSource.setUsername( "postgres" );
       dataSource.setPassword( "xxx" );
       return dataSource;
    }



    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
       JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
       transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

       return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
       return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
       Properties properties = new Properties();
       properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
       properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
       properties.setProperty("hibernate.query.factory_class", "org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory");
       return properties;
    }
}
```

But when I build and start my application i get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in com.vsb.cmms.web.config.PersistanceJPAConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'entityManagerFactory' or 'persistenceUnitName' is required
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5179)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1404)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1394)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'entityManagerFactory' or 'persistenceUnitName' is required
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet(JpaTransactionManager.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
... 21 more
```

The error is saying that'entityManagerFactory' or 'persistenceUnitName' is required. But entity manager factory should be provided via entityManagerFactory().
When I debbuged thi bean I noticed that em.getObject() is returning null and possibly is causing the error although I do not know why is this happening. I am using Spring 4 and Hibernate 5.2.3.Final.

Comment: "'entityManagerFactory' or 'persistenceUnitName' is required". What isn't clear in that? And where do you see a NullPointerException?

Comment: I noticed that but this error is caused by entityManagerFactory() because it is returning null my question is: why and how to fix it.

Comment: Can you check if the class annotated with @Entity is present in this package com.vsb.cmms.domain

Answer (score 0):

Your `entityManagerFactory()` method really shouldn't be calling `#getObject()` but instead you should write it as:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
   LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
   em.setDataSource(dataSource());
   em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.vsb.cmms.domain" });

   JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
   em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
   em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

   // just return the bean here
   return em;
}
```

Spring handles that factory bean automatically giving your `EntityManagerFactory` instances.

Comment: If I change it error dissapears but EntityManager or EntityManagerFacotry is null in my DAO class.

Comment: are you injecting it using `@PersistenceContext` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just found in the deeps of the internet...
If you want to make xml-less hibernate configuration with a chance easily control session(session for application or session for transaction), then you probably want to see [this](https://github.com/reborne/SmartHibernateConnector)

Please note, the code as it is works perfectly until Hibernate 5.2 version